# Is there a way to print all velocity context?

Tags: java, velocity

I've got a velocity template and a legacy method that puts something in the context for this template.

Can I know all the variables that are enabled in the template?
May be something like that:

```
#printContext()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
 #foreach( $key in $context.keys )
    $key = $context.get($key)
  #end
```

**See also:**

- [ContextTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ContextTool.html)
- [Interface Context](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/context/Context.html)